# setting non-integer line height in Lighttable

Tags: fonts, settings, lighttable

Adjusting the line height is a very nice feature of Lighttable. Following the documentation, I'm modifying the User behaviors with:

```clj
;; The editor tag is applied to all editors
:editor [:lt.objs.editor/no-wrap
         (:lt.objs.style/set-theme "default")
         (:lt.objs.style/font-settings "Ubuntu" 12 1.5)
    ]
```

However, I'm getting a quite erratic behavior when putting a *non-integer* line height (here `1.5`). When saving the file, the automatic refresh sometimes work, sometimes not. When I put an integer height instead (say `1` or `2`), it reloads perfectly.

So I'm wondering: is it allowed to put non-integer line height? Or is there just a bug in the reload process?

Comment: I have 1.4 line-height and I can't see any problems.

Comment: @AlešRoubíček For me 1.x works as well, but only after closing and reopening Lighttable. Are you able to get flawless live refresh, without restart for fractional values ?

Comment: I see, you are right. Open a ticket on github.

Comment: Done https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/1696 
@AlešRoubíček Thanks for your feedback. We'll see what comes out of it.